# Android (Java) displaying wind direction

Tags: java, android, graphics, gps, location

I am trying to display the direction of the wind using an arrow icon in relation to where the user is. The arrow should adjust to reflect any change in wind direction.

Currently I am using the OpenWeatherMap API to get the wind direction. It returns the wind in degrees. See code below.

```
OwmClient owm = new OwmClient();
WeatherStatusResponse currentWeather = owm.currentWeatherAroundPoint(53.326699f,-6.350769f,1);

WeatherData weather = currentWeather.getWeatherStatus().get(0);
double currentWindSpeed = weather.getWind().getSpeed() * 2.236936;

int windDirection = weather.getWind().getDeg();
System.out.print("Wind Direction is " + windDirection)
```

However I would like to take this return value and display the wind direction with an arrow that will change/adjust relative to direction of the user is moving in.

Or if easier giving the longitude and latitude of a location display the wind direction same way in relation to that point.

I would appreciate any help on how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Look at using sin & cos of the angle to give x&y of the line arrow.

Comment: First step would be to get a N/E/S/W view like a compass and have your wind direction update on that view based on the angle.  Then you should look at some Compass sample apps to see how the orientation sensor is used and rotate the entire compass view (wind direction and all) based on the sensor readings.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Cliff could you please elaborate on your sin & cos solution?                                                                                                  Kris, I found this [link](https://github.com/iutinvg/compass) compass example. Do you reckon it is a good example to try apply the wind direction to?

Comment: Do you the arrow to rotate as the user turns the Phone in relation to the earth? What are you showing the arrow on ? a map?